# Inequality with squares of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to prove that if $A, E$ are Hermitian square complex matrixes, then the folowing inequality holds:
$$\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} (\lambda_{i}(A + E) - \lambda_{i}(A))^{2} \le ||E||^{2}_{F}$$
Index $i$ is for sorted eigenvalues. 
Actually, I have no ideas how to start.

Comment: Where is this coming from? Is it an exercise? If so, perhaps check the lecture notes for some useful results. Also, is there any ordering of the eigenvalues here? What does $\lambda_i$ mean?

Comment: Yes, it is my task. $\lambda_{i}$ is eigenvalue. Yes, there is ordering, I mentioned this in post.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that works in the case where $A$ and $E$ are positive semidefinite. First, rewrite
$$
LHS = \sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda_i(A + E) - \lambda_i(A))^2 = \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2(A) + \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i^2(A+E) - 2\sum_{i=1}\lambda_i(A) \lambda_i(A + E) = \\
\|A\|_F^2 + \|A + E\|_F^2 - 2\sum_{i=1}\lambda_i(A) \lambda_i(A + E).
$$
Now, by [Von Neumann's trace inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#Von_Neumann%27s_trace_inequality_and_related_results), we have $\sum_{i} \lambda_i(A) \lambda_i(A + E) \geq \operatorname{tr}(A(A + E))$. Thus, we have
$$
LHS \geq \|A + E\|_F + \|A\|_F  - 2 \operatorname{tr}((A + E)A) = \|(A + E) - A\|_F = \|E\|_F,
$$
which was what we wanted.

Comment: $\le$ should be in last line.  However thank you, intersting approach, maybe it is possible to finish it not only for positive-semidefinite